# Histogram given y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I know that `plt.hist()` method needs `x-axis` as argument to be plotted.
But I have the following situation:

```
id   cluster_number
 1               10
 2               21
 3               55
 4               36
 5               70
 .                .
 .                .
 .                .
```

if I use `my_serie = df.groupby('cluster_number')['id'].size()`, the output would be a `Serie` with the number of `id's` in each cluster.

Then, with `plt.plot(my_serie)`, I get a `plot` with:

- `x-axis`: number of clusters...
- `y-axis`: with a given number of `id's`

Of course, this type of data would fit better in a histogram. But `plt.hist()` will understand the serie given as input as an `x-axis` values, not `y-axis` values, as understood by `plt.plot()`:

- `x-axis`: number of `id's` in a cluster...
- `y-axis`: and number of clusters with that number of `id's` read in `x-axis`

How can I get a histogram with `x-axis` and `y-axis` arrangement equal to `plt.plot()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this be a bar plot:

```
my_serie = df.groupby('cluster_number')['id'].size()
my_serie.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm newbie to matplotlib, and there is a lot I don't know :)